# No contract flake

Tags: business

What would you do if a director keeps flaking on giving you a contract/crew form to get your slice of the pie?

It's one of my first professional projects.

Answer (score 2):

Have you started the project yet?

I rarely get contracts, more often I get a deal memo which is simpler & states the basic terms (project/schedule/rates/payment schedule/overtime rates etc)

You could always provide your own deal memo and ask them to sign it? 
There are plenty of example deal memoes online if you do a search...

http://www.filmunderground.com/72/Article/NWFS/Deal%20Memos.htm
http://www.trewaudio.com/audioflow/2009/01/22/doing-a-deal

Comment: Yes.  The project is actually done but still needs some mixing.

Comment: The project is done? A bit late to get a contract in place. At this point you should be reminding your director/producer of the number you agreed upon a the beginning of the project and make sure they understand that you and your crew need to be paid, asap.

Comment: Yeah thats kinda what I'm doing.  Reminding him.  He recently asked us to finish it up so it can be burned on cds and boxed, "whatever version (out of 3)," and "at my convenience."
